# How to set the endpoint to publish with Django REST Swagger

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, django-rest-swagger

I have a large API REST project with **Django Rest Framework**, and I want to document it with **Django REST Swagger**, but I want this **Swagger** documentation to include only some of the endpoints of my whole project.

This is my `urls.py` where I set **Swagger** in my project:

```
from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path('api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token),
    path('', include('FrontEndApp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('docs/',get_swagger_view(title="Intellibook API")),
    path('rosetta/', include('rosetta.urls')),
    path('general/', include('GeneralApp.urls')),
    path('operations_manager/', include('OperationsManagerApp.urls')),
    path('payments_manager/', include('PaymentsManagerApp.urls')),
    #path('providers_manager/', include('ProvidersManagerApp.urls')),
    path('rates_manager/', include('RatesManagerApp.urls')),
    path('reports_manager/', include('ReportsManagerApp.urls')),
    path('reservations_manager/', include('ReservationsManagerApp.urls')),
    path('users_manager/', include('UsersManagerApp.urls')),
    path('excursions_manager/', include('ExcursionsManagerApp.urls')),
    path('invoices_manager/', include('InvoicesManagerApp.urls'))
)
```

Currently, **Swagger** publishes all the endpoints that are in all `urls.py` along the whole project. I want to set it to publish only the endpoints in `ursl.py` of only on of the apps of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Look into

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    "exclude_namespaces": [],    #  List URL namespaces to ignore
}
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find the docs. But if I get this right, you should split your urlpatterns into two parts, one for published, second for non published.